# Deletar sem dar erro

Tags: python, django

Tenho dois models, um tem a chave estrangeira no outro.

Queria implementar um `delete`, que impedisse que deletasse essa chave quando ela estivesse já salva num relacionamento.

Na `view.py` eu implementei, porém não consigo excluir nenhum. Eu acho que o erro está no `if` que está na view.

Models.py

```
class Horario(models.Model):
    horario = models.CharField('Horário', max_length=11, help_text='Ex= 00:00/00:00')
```

```
class Alocar(models.Model):
    data = models.DateField('Data', auto_now=True, blank=True)
    horario = models.ForeignKey(Horario, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    turma = models.ForeignKey(Turma, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    sala = models.ForeignKey(Sala, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

view.py

```
@login_required
def DelHorario(request, id):
    context = {}
    horario = get_object_or_404(Horario, pk=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if horario.id > 0:
            messages.success(request, 'Não pode ser excluído, pois está sendo usado numa relação')
        else:
            horario.delete()
        return redirect('alocar:addhorario')
    context['horario'] = horario
    return render(request, 'alocar/delhorario.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viva o problema é que não podes efetivamente apagar um registo se ele existir noutra tabela como fk, viola a integridade referencial. Sendo no admin do Django não precisas de fazer nada ele já valida isso e mostra uma mensagem. Contudo, em custom code podes validar verificando se na tabela relacional existe registos com o operador "select_related".

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def DelHorario(request, id):
    values = Alocar.objects.select_related('horario').filter(horario__id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if values:
            messages.success(request, 'Não pode ser excluído, pois está sendo usado numa relação')
        else:
            horario = get_object_or_404(Horario, pk=id)
            horario.delete()
        return redirect('alocar:addhorario')
    return render(request, 'alocar/delhorario.html')
```

Comment: Boa dia...amigo assim como recorri a voce diretamente para pedir ajuda, e voce prontamente me ajudou...é mais que uma obrigação minha te agradecer... MUITISSIMO OBRIGAO, ajudou deveras...

Comment: Boas, ainda bem que ajudou. Contudo, ressalvo que fazendo por você, não sei se entendeu bem que fiz, ou seja, "select_related" é o equivalente ao inner join do sql e filtras pela fk do horário exstente, se não existir permite eliminar. Não sei se nesse projeto permite, mas existe ainda a possibilidade de utilizares classes para o CRUD dá uma olhada aqui  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/. Por último, define funções/métodos em lower case, as classes é que são definidas assim (DelHorario) ou seja pascalcase, eu avaliaria isso no teu projeto.

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova, veja se o ajuda nas próximas respostas: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6972/137387

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova - boa tarde, haveria a possibilidade de me ajudar mais uma vez nesse post - Salvar relatório no   Django Excel com filtro

Comment: Boas, dá aqui uma vista de olhos neste exemplo https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/29/how-to-export-to-excel.html. É isto que precisas?

Comment: Também tenho utilizado este, https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/packages/2016/08/11/django-import-export.html. Contudo é limitado ao número de rows, mais de 5K já é um problema. Ou seja, é um serviço síncrono, não contêm um mecanismo como um background worker que importa todos os registos depois do upload do ficheiro para o servidor.